# Meteor reactivity with postgreSQL instead of MongoDB

Tags: postgresql, meteor, publish-subscribe, reactive-programming

Is there any way to implement reactivity with other database such as PostgreSQL in [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor)? We need to have live updates with databases other than MongoDB.

Answer (score 6):

Currently (0.7.0.1), Meteor's only supported database is Mongodb which is very coupled with what is called Minimongo, a client side implementation that mimics the mongodb api and is what basically one of the core components that allow the magic behind Meteor's reactivity.

That being said, other (sql) databases are actually on Meteor's roadmap which you can follow on the Trello board at https://trello.com/c/6ugalZMG/54-additional-database-support and https://trello.com/c/Gf6YxFp2/42-sql-support

But currently, there are some third party initiatives such as the [meteor-sql smart package](https://github.com/andreioprisan/meteor-sql) on atmosphere which opens up the first opportunities to develop against SQL.

The full reactivity is what you need to handle, though. Since it is implemented using publish/subscribe/observe api's of meteor and actually don't care much about the underlying data structure. Mongodb is just there for general convenience, but you can implement just about anything as your reactive data source.

In fact [this video tutorial](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/vhdWPskmLjNDoqjYd) from eventedmind takes you through the steps of creating a custom reactive data source.